# passing array values from controller to view in cakephp

Tags: php

//controller

```
public function viewcategorys1() {
$this->loadModel("Category");
$total = $this->Category->find('all', array('fields' =>array('sum(Category.rate)   AS ctotal'), 'conditions'=>array('Category.parentid' => 0)));
$this->set('sum',$total);
print_r($total);
}
```

// view

```
<?php 
foreach($sum as $ctotal):
echo $ctotal['Category']['rate'];
endforeach;
?>
```

in controller i have written 'print_r' so that it shows out put as:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ctotal] => 16250 ) ) )
```

as per the code written in view file it shows the out put as:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: category[APP/View/Category/viewcategorys1.ctp, line 48]
Code Context
include - APP/View/Category/viewcategorys1.ctp, line 48
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 945
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 907
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 952
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 194
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96
```

How to print the value i.e 16250 in my view.ctp file ?
    please help me

Comment: Is that all the data ?

Comment: it works ,thanks for helping

Comment: Good. Please mark this as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly print total on ctp

```
echo $total[0][0]['ctotal'];
```

Other way need to create virtual field

In Modal

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'ctotal' => 'sum(Category.rate)'
);
```

In controller

```
public function viewcategorys1() {
$this->loadModel("Category");
$total = $this->Category->find('all', array('fields' =>array('Category.ctotal'), 'conditions'=>array('Category.parentid' => 0)));
$this->set('sum',$total);
print_r($total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
<?php 
  foreach($sum[0] as $ctotal):
   echo $ctotal['ctotal'];
  endforeach;
?>
```